# Write a wrapper to expose existing REST APIs as SOAP web services?

Tags: django, python-3.x, rest, soap, django-rest-framework

I have existing REST APIs, written using Django Rest Framework and now due to some client requirements I have to expose some of them as SOAP web services.

I want to know how to go about writing a wrapper in python so that I can expose some of my REST APIs as SOAP web services. OR should I make SOAP web services separately and reuse code ?

I know this is an odd situation but any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: And ? What's your question exactly ?

Comment: I want to know how to go about writing a wrapper in python so that I can expose some of my REST APIs as SOAP web services. OR should I make SOAP web services separately and reuse code ?

Comment: Well what have you tried ?

Comment: Currently I am evaluating both the options. I am more inclined towards writing separate SOAP web services and then reusing internal code. But the problem is that in future I may have to expose more of these APIs in form of SOAP web service so I am thinking that maybe some sort of wrapper could be used to have these APIs exposed both as SOAP web service and REST APIs.

Answer (score 10):

You can say, `SOAP` and `REST` are basically `apples` and `oranges`.

You basically need something, where you can consume the REST API's.

As I see, you have some options:

- Use a SOAP service separately running on another port (endpoint). For that I would say, use framework's like [Spyne](http://spyne.io/docs/2.9/manual/02_helloworld.html#manual-helloworld) check out sample [hello world](http://spyne.io/#inprot=HttpRpc&outprot=Soap11&s=rpc&tpt=DjangoApplication&validator=true)
- Use the clients preferred way, either SOAP via WSGI or SOAP via [HttpRPC](https://github.com/arskom/spyne/blob/master/examples/helloworld_http.py)
- Invoke the same REST API endpoints which you created via the methods in SOAP.
  We had used an internal api wrapper in one of application, which is as:

```
def wrap_internal_api_call(requests_api_method, uri, 
                           data, cookies=None, headers=None):

    return requests_api_method(uri, data=data, files=files, 
               cookies=cookies, headers=headers)
```

How you can use this?

```
import requests

from django.core.urlresolvers import reverse
from django.conf import settings

from spyne.service import Service
from spyne.decorator import srpc
from spyne.model import ByteArray, DateTime, Uuid, String, Integer, Integer8, \
    ComplexModel, Array


# This method will hit the internal API which is written in DJANGO REST FRAMEWORK
def build_internal_uri(uri):
  return 'http://localhost:{0}{1}'.format(settings.INTERNAL_API_PORT, uri)


class RequestHeader(ComplexModel):
  some_field = String


class SomeService(Service):
    # Headers related doc
    # https://github.com/arskom/spyne/blob/68b9d5feb71b169f07180aaecfbe843d8ba500bf/doc/source/manual/06_metadata.rst#protocol-headers 
    __in_header__ = RequestHeader

  @srpc(String, _returns=String)
  def echo_string(s):
    headers = ctx.in_header.some_field

    # Reverse url from the urls.py file
    local_order_fetch_url = build_internal_uri(reverse('website:order_details')) + '?order_id=' + order_id

    response = wrap_internal_api_call(requests.get, local_order_fetch_url, 
            { 'data': 'sample_data' }, None, headers)

    return response['data'] # Some string data


app = Application([SomeService], 'tns', in_protocol=HttpRpc(parse_cookie=True), 
                out_protocol=HttpRpc())
```

Now there are some of examples which you can look into, being the Django configuration for making it [available](https://github.com/arskom/spyne/blob/68b9d5feb71b169f07180aaecfbe843d8ba500bf/doc/source/manual/05-03_django.rst)

Answer (score 0):

Lets Discuss both the Approaches and their pros and cons

**Seperate SOAP Service**

- **Reusing Same Code** -  if you are sure the code changes will not impact the two code flow ,it is good to go.
- **Extension of Features** - if you are sure that new feature extension will not impact other parts it is again best to go.
- **Scalablity** - if new API are part of same application and you are sure that it will be scalable with more load ,it is again a good option.
- **Extension** - if you are sure in future adding more API will not create a mess of code, it is again good to go for.

**Soap Wrapper Using Python** (my favourate and suggested way to go)

- **Seperation of Concern** with this you can make sure ,what ever code you write is sperate from main logic and you can easly plug in and plug out new things.

Answer for all the above question in case of this is YES.

Your Call ,

**Comments and critisicsm are most welcome**

Comment: Before down voting please let me know the reason